# bash : concatenate each file from a directory except one

Tags: bash, file

Hello everyone and thanks for your time !

I have a directory with n files. I need, in another dedicated directory, to concatenate all the files except the first one into "group1", then all the files except the second one to "group2" etc.

I tried this :

```
for f in dir/*
do
    cat !($f) > otherdir/group$f
done
```

But it seems like cat doesn't work that way since I get a syntax error : (I'm roughtly translating the error given in my language)

```
syntax error near unexpected symbol : (
line : cat !($f) > otherdir/group$f
```

I also tried to workaround by first copy all the needed files somewhere, concatenate, then delete them. But as it will have to work with huge and multiple files, I'd prefer to not have to write useless files.

Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps you should post what the syntax error says?

Comment: BTW, you can usually get the English translation by setting `LANG=C` (or `LANG=en`, I think).

Comment: For this case the rought translation seemed enough for me, I just wanted to prevent any comment like "your error message is odd." But I'll keep it in mind if I ever need to get the exact error message, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first set `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob
cd dir
for f in *
do
    cat !("$f") > "../otherdir/group$f"
done
```

`extglob` is needed because `!($f)` is called an extended glob pattern which is not set by default. See `man bash` for more details on `extglob`

Comment: A small explanation along side the answer would be nice.

Comment: Thanks @Jite, I added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the following error : cat: !(dir/1): no file or directory of this type (I'm roughly translating, my terminal is set to my language)